# MQTT subscription much slower than publishing

Tags: python, performance, mqtt, micropython, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I am using MQTT to transfer sonar sensor data from an EV3DEV device to a PC. In order to do that I've set-up the MQTT Mosquitto broker on ubuntu running under Microsoft's Windows Linux Subsystem (WLS) as shown in image bellow.

[image: Schematic of current arquitecture]

On the EV3DEV end, I am using umqtt.simple module and on the PC side I am using Paho MQTT module.

The messages from the EV3DEV to the broker seem to be flowing fast as I expected (at a similar rate as I could experiment when I used socks in an earlier version) The problem appears on the subscriber side, where I can see the messages are being received at a MUCH SLOWER rate, causing the messages to queue in the browser. When I stop the EV3DEV even after just a few seconds, I keep getting messages on the PC for quite some time.

Is this performance difference reasonable? I was expecting MQTT to add some additional latency to the data transmission as compared to a plain sock communication, but I was certainly not expecting such a big difference in through output between the MQTT message sending and the message subscription.

ADDITIONAL NOTES
- I installed mosquito under WLS because it seemed easier and the windows version did not seem to work just by installing it.
- I am not sure of the rate at which I am sending the messages. Probably as fast as the broker takes them since it is in a loop dedicated to get the sensor data and send it to the broker. The issue, in any case, is that the rate at which the broker is accepting messages from the publisher is much higher than the rate at which it is sending the messages to the subscriber.
- Here is a sample of the code I use on the on_message callback function:

```
def ProcessMessage(self, client, userdata, msg):
    logging.info("Message received from broker:" +msg.payload.decode())
    Switch = {'robot/sonar': self.PutInSonarQueue, "robot/odo": 
    self.PutInOdometryQueue}
    payloadasobject = ast.literal_eval(msg.payload.decode())
    Switch[msg.topic](payloadasobject)
```

The switch statement calls functions that simply put the message in a queue.

Comment: About how many messages per second are we talking? Remember that the focus of MQTT is not speed but transport in less reliable networks with optional QoS.

Comment: Edit the question to include the `on_message` callback in your python code so we can see how you are handling messages. Also any particular reason you installed mosquitto in the WLS rather than natively in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
It seems I was overwhelming the message broker with a message rate that was too high for it to handle.
Now, instead of a continuous loop, I make it sleep for 50 milliseconds between message publications and now the subscriber seems to be receiving the messages more or less at the same rate as they are sent.